# Getting "SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax", but don't know why

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Getting "SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax", but don't know why

```
  File "cursor4.py", line 138
    global D=-1*((self.meteor_x_coordlist[i]-self.meteor_x_coordlist[i+1])+(self.meteor_y_coordlist[i]-self.meteor_y_coordlist[i+1]))
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the code:

```
for i in range(8):
    if ((self.meteor_x_coordlist[i]-self.meteor_x_coordlist[i+1])+(self.meteor_y_coordlist[i]-self.meteor_y_coordlist[i+1])) < 0:
        global D=-1*((self.meteor_x_coordlist[i]-self.meteor_x_coordlist[i+1])+(self.meteor_y_coordlist[i]-self.meteor_y_coordlist[i+1]))
    if D**0.5<(self.sizelist[i]/2)+(self.sizelist[i+1]/2):
        #print "-----------------------"
        self.meteorlist.remove(self.meteorlist[i])
        if self.meteorlist == []:
            pass   #psu
```

Comment: You can't use the `global` keyword in an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it's because you're using `global` here in a weird way. Looking at [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/), maybe do it like this:

```
global D
for i in range(8):
    test = ((self.meteor_x_coordlist[i]-self.meteor_x_coordlist[i+1])+(self.meteor_y_coordlist[i]-self.meteor_y_coordlist[i+1]))
    if test < 0:
        D=-1*test
    if D**0.5<(self.sizelist[i]/2)+(self.sizelist[i+1]/2):
        #print "-----------------------"
        self.meteorlist.remove(self.meteorlist[i])
        if self.meteorlist == []:
            pass   #psu
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine a `global` statement with an assignment. If you need both, put them on separate lines:

```
global D
D = whatever
```

But using global variables is often a bad idea in the first place. Usually you can get by using locals or instance variables in object oriented code. Using instance variables is much better than using globals, as you can have many objects in use at the same time, without them all tripping over each other using the same variable names.

If you just added the `global` line to fix an issue with `D`, it's probably because you're only assigning to it conditionally, and the next `if` test expects it to always have a value. In that case, you probably want to keep `D` a local variable, you'll just need to initialize it before starting the loop:

```
D = initial_value

for i in range(8):
    if something:
        D = new_value

    if some_condition(D): # this line requires D to always have a value!
        ... # do stuff
```